# Strange behaviour of Regex to allow only alphabets in the name field

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I have a validatio rule on contact which gives error when the name field contains non-alphabetic character.

Formual for the Vaildation rule is as follows :

```
OR(
   REGEX( FirstName , "[a-zA-Z]+"),
   REGEX( LastName , "[a-zA-Z]+"),
   REGEX( Subscriber_Middle_Name__c , "[a-zA-Z]*") 
 )
```

Strange behaviour is that the above regex does not work. It works when I use NOT() with it as given below.

```
OR(
   NOT( REGEX( FirstName , "[a-zA-Z]+")),
   NOT( REGEX( LastName , "[a-zA-Z]+")),
   NOT( REGEX( Subscriber_Middle_Name__c , "[a-zA-Z]*")) 
 )
```

Though it is exact opposite of what I want; it works. What is the possible reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex Returns TRUE if Text matches the regular expression RegEx_Text. Therefore if you Field is right then it gets true as result.

For Validation rules - If this formula expression is true, display the text defined in the Error Message area.

It's fine behavior then (at least it works as described in docs)